# Least Upper Bound Property

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

Note that a non-empty set which is bounded above always has a least upper bound, by Axiom the completness axiom. However, it need not have a maximum.

My question is that why not need have a maximum?

Answer (score 1):

Take for example the set $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ where $a<b$. This set is nonempty and has least upper bound $b$. But since this set does not include the endpoints it does not have a largest element since we can get arbitrarily close to $b$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Think an open or semiopen interval, for example [0,1) 1 is the supremum of this set for > relation, but can´t be the maximum because it is not in the set. Anyway, if the least upper bound it is in the set, then it is his maximum, of course. In discrete sets:natural, integers numbers, etc....the least upper bound is always the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

First let me make you clear what is maximum of a POSET.Maximum is that element of a POSET which is in the set and is greatest of all the element of the set. So completeness axiom only tells you about the LUB(or GLB) and not about the maximum(or minimum).

For example, take the set (0,1) according to completeness axiom it has a supremum i.e., 1 but it doesn't have any maximum cause you cannot find the maximum element in the set. If you assume 0.999999999 as the maximum, i can provide another number 0.999999999999(say) which is larger than the number that you provided. Similarly, someone else can provide another number 0.999999999999999999(say) which is again larger than the number i provided to be the maximum. So, its a game that doesn't ends. Thus it doesn't have any maximum.